# How to pre-render multiple Vue app pages?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, server-side-rendering

I'm trying (unsuccessfully) to pre-render the HTML of multiple Vue apps within the same project scaffolded with Vue CLI. I do not want to use Vue Router or Nuxt etc for multiple reasons.

I've tried using [prerender-spa-plugin](https://github.com/chrisvfritz/prerender-spa-plugin), but since I don't use routes, it only pre-renders the index.

My vue.config.js looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const PrerenderSPAPlugin = require('prerender-spa-plugin');

const Renderer = PrerenderSPAPlugin.PuppeteerRenderer;

module.exports = {
  pages: {
    index: 'src/index.js',
    about: 'src/about.js',
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new PrerenderSPAPlugin({
        staticDir: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        routes: ['/'],

        postProcess(route) {
          route.html = route.html.replace('</script><div>', '</script><div id="app" data-server-rendered="true">');

          return route;
        },

        renderer: new Renderer({
          headless: true,
          renderAfterDocumentEvent: 'render-event',
        }),
      }),
    ],
  },
};
```

and my index.js and about.js essentially look like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './Index.vue';

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  mounted() {
    document.dispatchEvent(new Event('render-event'));
  },
}).$mount('#app');
```

I also have unique public/ index.html and about.html pages.

The `routes` parameter of prerender-spa-plugin doesn't seem to recognise things like `'/about.html'`. Is there an easy way of achieving multiple pre-rendered pages?

Do I have to wrestle with the SSR module?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wonder how does  your spa knows what to serve  if not told by Route? As per docs the `route` param takes multiple routes - my guess is you just leave the spa in any other path than /

Comment: That's the thing, I don't want a SPA. I just want multiple pages within the same "application" that can be browsed to normally and share data as necessary.

Comment: ah - i missed you are using pages option - maybe you are using only index.html as entry - try explicit: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages -> `dist/{filename}.html` - just a guess cant test right now

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. If `filename` is omitted, then its inferred from the entry. Pages all work in dev mode, it's just trying to figure out how to pre-render it is the hard bit. I'm not sure the prerender plugin supports MPAs

Comment: checking https://github.com/JoshTheDerf/prerenderer/search?q=renderRoutes&unscoped_q=renderRoutes actually points to routes param not correct, rly weird..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I've found is to call `new PrerenderSPAPlugin` multiple times, one for each route.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing the same issue, i have static html uses vue component and i want to pre-render the vue component in output build directory. I'm using laravel-mix package for build process.
Could you post the full solution for this i.e calling new PrerenderSPAPlugin multiple times, one for each route.

If i can get the full webpack.config.js, it would easy for me to understand and implement the same using laravel-mix.