# How can I prerender a subset of my laravel+vue application?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, prerender

I have a laravel application with my front-end written in Vuejs. I want to prerender the public pages only. What is the correct configuration for the prerender-spa-plugin to do this?

Most tutorials on the web show how to do it for the whole website, but I need only few pages pre-rendered. I must be missing something but I get only a blank page and my javascript is not loaded during the prerendering. I am not using vue router.

```
const path = require('path')
const PrerenderSPAPlugin = require('prerender-spa-plugin')

// In the mix webpack config - 

  plugins: [
    ...
    new PrerenderSPAPlugin({
      // Required - The path to the webpack-outputted app to prerender.
      staticDir: path.join(__dirname, 'static'),
      // Required - Routes to render.
      routes: [ '/' ],
    })
  ]
```

Error message: Unable to prerender all routes!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pre-render multiple Vue app pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57141088/how-to-pre-render-multiple-vue-app-pages)

Answer (score 0):

The javascript/vue files etc for the static part should all be in the static directory. It won't work if they are in the folder you normally use for organizing the rest of your application.

You need to use HTMLwebpackPlugin to copy over the html to the output directory (say, in public). Mix's copy happens too late. Chunks will help get only the js files you want.